# Add value or text to column a if condition in column b is met pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I keep getting nan for this, so hoping for a quick fix.

df:

```
cola    colb
5       30
10      95
```

I'd like to add 20 to cola if colb is between 90 and 100, like this:

```
cola    colb
5       30
30      95
```

Code i'm working with:

```
df['cola'] = df.loc[df['colb'].between(90,100), 'cola'] + 20
```

And bonus points - i have another column with text, i'd like to append a string if the condition is met, like this:

```
cola    colb    colc
5       30      some_text
30      95      some_text, condition_met
```

Code for this one that also returns nan is:

```
df['colc'] = df.loc[df['colb'].between(90,100), 'colc'] + 'condition_met'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
# Create input dataframe using copy to clipboard
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df['colc'] = 'some text'

# No need to iterate use pandas intrinsic data
# alignment with the addition assignment operator

df.loc[df['colb'].between(90,100), 'cola'] += 20
df.loc[df['colb'].between(90,100), 'colc'] += ', condition met'
df
```

Output:

```
   cola  colb                      colc
0     5    30                 some text
1    30    95  some text, condition met
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've just slightly misunderstood [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). Minimally `loc` should be on the left-hand side for assignment. It can be on both. Additionally, if the same condition is to be reused it can be saved as a variable like `m` below.

Something like:

```
m = df['colb'].between(90, 100)
df.loc[m, 'cola'] = df.loc[m, 'cola'] + 20
df.loc[m, 'colc'] = df.loc[m, 'colc'] + ', condition_met'
```

`df`

```
   cola  colb                      colc
0     5    30                 some text
1    30    95  some text, condition_met
```

---

DataFrame and imports:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'cola': [5, 10], 'colb': [30, 95],
                   'colc': ['some text', 'some text']})
print(df)
```

`df`

```
   cola  colb       colc
0     5    30  some text
1    10    95  some text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `agg`:

```
mask = df['colb'].between(90, 100)

df.loc[mask, ['cola', 'colc']] = \
    df[mask].agg({'cola': lambda x: x+20,
                  'colc': lambda s: ', '.join([s, 'condition_met'])})
```

```
>>> df
   cola  colb                      colc
0     5    30                 some_text
1    30    95  some_text, condition_met
```

Answer (score 1):

To tackle both issues together, I would iterate over the dataframe like this:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if 90 < row['colb'] < 100: 
        row['cola'] = row['cola'] + 20 
        row['colc'] = row['colc'] + ', condition_met'
```